# Cassandra: get_range_slices of TimeUUID super column?

Tags: perl, cassandra

I have a schema of Row Keys 1-n. In each row there are a variable number of supercolumns with a TimeUUID 'name'. Im hoping to be able to query this data by a time range.

Two issues have come up:

in KeyRange -> the values that I put in for 'start_key' and 'end_key' are getting misunderstood (for lack of a better term) by Thrift. Experimenting with different groups of values Im not seeing what I expect and often get back something completely unexpected.

Example: my row keys are running from 1-1000 with lots of random gaps. I put start_key = 50 and end_key = 20 .. and I get back rows with keys ranging from 99 to 414.

Example: I have a known row with key = 13. Putting this value into start_key and end_key gives me no results.

Second issue: even when I do get results the 'columns' portion of the 'keyslice' is always empty. I have checked via cassandra-cli and I know there is data.

Im using Perl as follows:

```
my $slice_range = new Cassandra::SliceRange();
$slice_range->{ start } = create_UUID( UUID::Tiny::UUID_TIME, "2010-12-24 00:00:00" );
$slice_range->{ finish } = create_UUID( UUID::Tiny::UUID_TIME, "2011-12-25 00:00:00" );

my $slice_predicate = new Cassandra::SlicePredicate();
$slice_predicate->{ slice_range } = $slice_range;

my $key_range = new Cassandra::KeyRange();
$key_range->{ start_key } = 13;
$key_range->{ end_key } = 13;

my $result = $client->get_range_slices( $column_parent, $slice_predicate, $key_range, $consistency_level );  

print Dumper( $result );
```

Clearly Im misunderstanding some basic precept.

EDIT: It turns out that the Perl library Im using is not properly documented. The UUID creation was not working as advertised. I opened it up, fixed it, and now its all going a bit more as I was expecting. I can slice my supercolumns by date/time range. Still working on getting the key range portion to work.

Comment: What partitioner are you using? If you are using the RandomPartitioner  you will not be able to do row key slices.

Comment: Oh dear. I thought the issue with RP was that the results wouldn't be sorted. Not that it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Actually - I would be using a single row key for each slice. Its the column keys that Im range slicing... or hoping to..

Comment: If you are fetching from a single row, use get_slice instead of get_range_slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#range_rp covers why you're not seeing what you expect with key ranges.

You need to specify a SlicePredicate that contains the actual range of what you're trying to select.  The default of no column_names and no slice_range will result in the empty columns list that you see.